# how to create a link which pops up a conversation box in html?

Tags: html, popup

I am trying to create in html a link which will be presented as a set of words and when someone presses the words a pop up will show up. I would also like to control the options in the pop up, what is written inside it. can someone tell me how to do that? **I do not want a button, I want words only which can be pressed on to pop up a message.

Comment: You'll need to use Javascript to parse your content and make clickable words.

Answer (score 1):

Without JavaScript, I fear this is not possible.
Is this something you envision?

```
<p id="popup">Word</p>
<div id="box"></div>

<script>

document.querySelector('#popup').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const message = "This is my message";
    document.querySelector('#box').innerText = message;
    document.querySelector('#box').addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.querySelector('#box').innerText = '';
    });
});

</script>
```

Click the word to fill the 'pop up' and click the 'pop up' to empty it again.